# Greater area for radio selection

Tags: jquery, select, click, radio-button

```
<span>
   <img src="img/icon.png" alt="" />
   <label><input type="radio" name="" /> Label here</label>
</span>
```

I want the whole `<span>` to be clickable, not just the radio input. How do I do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better way.

```
$('span').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input').attr({checked:"checked"});
});
```

Just keep in mind that you are adding a click event to *all spans*. Better would be to have a class on the span and reference that.

```
$('.myClickySpan')...

<span class='myClickySpan'>...
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, the easiest solution would be to wrap everything inside the `<label>` tag, like this:

```
<label for="foo">
    <img src="img/icon.png" alt="" />
    <input type="radio" name="" id="foo" />
</label>
```

When you specify an `for` attribute to label, and the same `id` to the field, the label becomes clickable and will activate the corresponding input.

But, if you for some reason need to do it in jQuery, this should work:

```
$('span').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input').click();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: you don't need the `for` attribute if the input is already inside the label

Comment: @Raveren, you're correct but I like to keep it in there, it adds a bit readability in my opinion.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't this cause something of an infinite loop because of event bubbling? Or am I mistaken? EDIT: Just tested it, and it does. You should use .select() instead of .click().

Comment: I was wrong about .select(). It should be $(this).find('input').attr({checked:true});

Comment: @patrick, you're right, I corrected my sample. Simple `return false;` is enough. :) Changing the `checked` attr would require to first check the state and set it to the opposite, your example sets it always on.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: Since these are radios and not checkboxes, there's no need to check the state. Clicking on an already selected radio should not unselect it.

Comment: @patrick, you're right, didn't take that into account. Either way, my example should be working now.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: I know this one is a couple days old, but the **infinite loop** remains. Returning false does nothing if it is after the click() causing the loop. Better to correct it so that a future reader doesn't use it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it without jQuery by just making the `<span>` the `<label>` instead:

```
<label for="some-id">
   <img src="img/icon.png" alt="" />
   <input type="radio" name="" id="some-id" /> Label here
</label>
```

Comment: Yes it will. IE respects labels just like every other browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").click(function(){
  var radio = $(this).find('input:radio');
  //do whatever with the radio button
});
```

I believe should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the `for` attribute of the [label](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp). Maybe doing so will help you

```
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r" />
<label for="r">
   <img src="img/icon.png" alt="" />
   Label here
</label>
```